# Objective-C - Directly call method from array of objects

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective C, and I'm trying to call a method on an array (NSArray) of objects directly like this:

```
[[myPeople objectAtIndex: 0] setName: @"Shane"];
```

But this doesn't seem to work, and returns a warning saying "Multiple methods named 'setName' found"

I can successfully perform the operation in this manner:

```
Person* person = [myPeople objectAtIndex: 0];
[person setName: @"Shane"];
```

Is my syntax simply incorrect in the first case, or should the second piece of code be used? Or is there a better way that I'm not aware of?

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Note that if you have two declarations of `setName:` where the argument or return type are different, then you are writing code against the recommended conventions of the system.   Rename one of the methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it to all objects in the array like this:

`[myPeople makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setName:) withObject:@"Shane"];`

Answer (score 3):

The first syntax is correct and will work correctly, despite the warning.  The compiler is warning you because it can't verify the type of object that you're calling `setName:` on.

The method `objectAtIndex:` of the `NSArray` class returns the type `id`, which is a generic pointer to an Objective-C object of unknown type.  So, when you call `setName:` on the `id` that is returned, the compiler doesn't know what the actual class of the object is.  In your code, there are multiple classes that define the `setName:` method (possibly as a synthesized setter for a property named `name`), so it issues a warning.

The second code snippet compiles without warning because the `id` type can be implicitly cast to any other Objective-C pointer type.  When you say `Person* person = [myPeople objectAtIndex: 0];`, you're taking the `id` returned by `objectAtIndex:` and casting it (implicitly) to `Person*`.  Then, when you call `setName:` on that `Person`, the compiler knows what type you have, so it can verify that the class `Person` does in fact implement the `setName:` method.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to bypass the compiler warning. There are two other approaches then the one you demonstrated.

you can call performSelector:withObject on it.

```
[[myPeople objectAtIndex: 0] performSelector:@selector(setName:) withObject: @"Shane"];
```

usually with this method, you want to make sure it responds to the selector.

```
if ([[myPeople objectAtIndex: 0] respondsToSelector:@selector(setName:)])
```

another option is to cast the result

```
[(Person*)[myPeople objectAtIndex: 0] setName: @"Shane"];
```

these should eliminate the compiler warnings.